# Did Mary leave before John was born?

Tags: jesus, luke, john-the-baptist, mary

In Luke 1:26-27 it says Elizabeth was 6 month pregnant when God sent Gabriel to tell  Mary that she will become pregnant with Jesus as a virgin.

In Luke 1:39-40 we see just a few days later Mary hurried to Elizabeth, whom she was told by Gabriel was pregnant as well.

In Luke 1:56 it says Mary stayed with Elizabeth about three months before returning to her home.

In Luke 1:57 it tells us that Elizabeth gave birth to her son, John.

The timeline up to this point, points towards Mary being with Elizabeth in her ninth month of pregnancy. Did Mary stay for the birth of John or did she leave just before John was born as the text seems to suggest? If Mary did leave before John was born, why? She was excited enough to travel from Nazareth to Judea to see Elizabeth and celebrate their pregnancies together. She was also so excited she stayed with Elizabeth for the final three months of her pregnancy. So, why would she leave just before the baby was to be born?

Comment: Hello, Tony, and welcome to Hermeneutics.SE. I *think* this question has already been answered, but if you have question(s) that are not addressed there, please just [edit] this to specify and flag it so that we can re-open. Thanks!